# Control de estado por fechas y horas en Django

Tags: python, django, lógica

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy creando un sistema de información con el que pretendo poder "reservar" un recurso durante un periodo de tiempo determinado. Dicho recurso no podrá ser "reservado" nuevamente en el mismo periodo de tiempo, pero si puede ser "reservado" en un periodo de tiempo distinto.

Estos son los modelos relacionados en el desarrollo:

Usuario

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # campos del modelo. (username, email, etc)
```

Recurso

```
class Recurso(models.Model):
    # campos del recurso. (numero, caracteristicas, etc)
```

Recurso físico, puede ser un salón, un auditorio, etc.

```
class RecursoFisico(Recurso):
    # campos del recurso fisico. (capacidad, ubicacion, etc)
```

Recurso tecnologico, puede ser un video beam, una cabina de sonido, etc.

```
class RecursoTecnologico(Recurso):
    # campos del recurso fisico. (marca, referencia, etc)
```

A continuación  el modelo que me mostrara las reservas, por lo tanto sera mas completo.

Agenda

```
class Agenda(MarcadorTiempo):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recurso_fisico = models.ForeignKey(RecursoFisico, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Recurso fisico',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recurso_tecnologico = models.ManyToManyField(RecursoTecnologico, null=True, blank=True,
                                             verbose_name='Recurso Tecnologico', related_name='agenda_recurso')
    fecha_separacion = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Fecha de Separación')
    fecha_devolucion = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Fecha de Devolución')
```

Mi duda es la siguiente, como puedo reservar un recurso entre `fecha_separacion` 
y `fecha_devolucion` evitando que algún otro usuario lo reserve en ese mismo periodo de tiempo y dejándolo disponible en el resto del tiempo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Saludos te sugiero crear un campo estado/disponible donde este sea 1-> Disponible ..0-> No Disponible...entonces supongo que haces un querySet con el listado de Recursos..algo asi miRecurso.objects.all().filter(estado=1) , entonces solo mostrarias los disponibles y cada vez que se libere un recurso puedes hacer un update de este campo...

Comment: @DiegoAvila Habia pensado algo así, pero eso me deja sin el recurso hasta que lo libere el usuario que lo tomo. No podría agendar para otro momento.

Comment: Podrías solucionar tu problema con una señal `pre_save`, así te encargas de verificar que la instancia que se esta guardando no se guarde en el periodo incorrecto.

Comment: Y si quieres indicarle al usuario sobre que es periodo de tiempo incorrecto tienes que manejar eso en la vista como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Con este diseño de intervalo de fechas el problema se hace complejo. Imagina que en la DB existe una entrada de `Agenda` con el siguiente intervalo entre el día 10 y el día 20: `[10  ...   20]`. En este punto, si alguien quiere reservar otro recurso, tienes múltiples casos que resolver, entre ellos:

- 1) Reserva dentro de un intervalo existente (día 15 a 17): `[10    {15...17}    20]`
- 2) Reserva sobrepasando intervalo existente (del 17 al 22): `[10    {17...20]...22}`
- 3) Reserva pisando intervalo existente: `{5...[10...15}     20]`
- 4) Reserva envolviendo intervalo existente:  `{5...[10      20]...22}`

El problema en este caso no es programático (puedes usar señales o el método `full_clean()` de django para validar), el problema es de concepto ya que deberás validar todos los casos anteriores.

Por poner un ejemplo usando `full_clean()`:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Agenda(MarcadorTiempo):
    def full_clean(exclude=None, validate_unique=True):
        super(Agenda, self).full_clean(exclude, validate_unique)

        try:
            Agenda.objects.get(Q(
                recurso_fisico=self.recurso_fisico,
                # Cubre caso 1 y 2
                Q(
                    fecha_separacion__lt=self.fecha_separacion, 
                    fecha_devolucion__gt=self.fecha_separacion
                ) ||
                # Cubre caso 1 y 3
                Q(
                    fecha_separacion__lt=self.fecha_devolucion, 
                    fecha_devolucion__gt=self.fecha_devolucion
                ) ||
                # Cubre el caso 4
                Q(
                    fecha_separacion__gt=self.fecha_separacion,
                    fecha_devolucion__lt=self.fecha_devolucion
                )
            ))
            raise ValidationError('Recurso ocupado')
        except Agenda.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        except Agenda.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            raise ValidationError('Recurso ocupado')
```